# Migração dbExpress para FireDAC

Tags: mysql, delphi-xe6, firedac

Estou fazendo a migração de um sistema **dbExpress** para o ***FireDAC***, o sistema é em três camadas (*multtier*), mudei os componentes no lado servidor de `SQLConnection` para `FDConnection`, e os `SQLDataset` para `FDQuery`, no lado cliente os componentes continuam sendo o `ClientDataset`, porém vi que no `FDQuery` os campos do tipo `INT32` são lidos do banco de dados (*MySQL*) como `TLongWordFields` e não `TIntegerFields`, tenho cerca de cem `ClientDatasets` com os campos todos do tipo `TIntegerField`, tenho que fazer a mudança em todos ou existe outra forma de contornar isso?

Obs.: Os campos *auto incremento* são lidos no **FireDAC** como `TFDAutoIncField` e não `TIntegerField` porém não ocorre nenhum problema de incompatibilidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

No lado servidor, nos componentes que você trocou para `FDQuery`, você não precisa carrega os campos. Faça um teste, deixa apenas a consulta SQL no `FDQuery`, no lado cliente adicione um `ClientDataset` “novo, não reutilize ou copie é cole”, após isso carregue os campos no `ClientDataset`  e veja se os campos estão iguais.

Comment: carrega iguais, mas então que dizer que no firedac não existe TIntegerField?